# How do I find the limit of this function involving complex numbers as $x → 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, complex-numbers

I have the function

$$
f(x) = \frac{\Im\left(\frac{M^{x + 1} - m^{x + 1}}{M^x - m^x}\right) - \frac{\Im(a)}{2}}{\Re\left(\frac{M^{x + 1} - m^{x + 1}}{M^x - m^x}\right) - \frac{\Re(a)}{2}}
$$

where $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers, $M = \frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 + 4 b}}{2}$, $m = \frac{a - \sqrt{a^2 + 4 b}}{2}$, and $\Re(z)$ and $\Im(z)$ are the real and imaginary parts of any complex-valued $z$, respectively.

I want to know how to find the limit of this function as $x → 0$ in terms of $a$, $b$, $M$, and/or $m$. By plotting the function in graphing software I can see that the limit exists, as $\lim_{x → 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x → 0^-} f(x)$. However, the presence of the complex numbers is confusing me as to how to proceed.

**Edit with additional information on implementing Vishu's answer:**

The graphing software I'm using, GeoGebra, does not allow specifying which branch of the complex logarithm is used, so for some values of $a$ and $b$ Vishu's answer

$$
\lim_{x → 0} f(x) = \frac{
\Im\left(\frac{M - m}{\ln\left(\frac{M}{m}\right)}\right)
}{
\Re\left(\frac{M - m}{ln\left(\frac{M}{m}\right)}\right)
}
$$

appears to not work.

This can be fixed by instead using the equation

$$
\lim_{x → 0} f(x) = \frac{\Im\left(\frac{M - m}{\ln\left(\left|\frac{M}{m}\right|\right) + i \left(\arg\left(\frac{M}{m}\right) + 2 π k\right)}\right)}
{\Re\left(\frac{M - m}{\ln\left(\left|\frac{M}{m}\right|\right) + i \left(\arg\left(\frac{M}{m}\right) + 2 π k\right)}\right)}
$$

where $k$ is defined as

$$
k = \begin{cases}
1 & : 0 < \arg(b) ≤ π ∧ \arg(\sqrt{b}) ≤ \arg(M) ≤ \arg(b) ∨ -π ≤ \arg(b) < 0 ∧ \arg(-\sqrt{b}) ≤ \arg(M) ≤ π \\
−1 & : -π ≤ \arg(b) < 0 ∧ \arg(b) ≤ \arg(M) ≤ \arg(\sqrt{b}) ∨ 0 < \arg(b) ≤ π ∧ -π ≤ \arg(M) ≤ \arg(-\sqrt{b}) \\
0 & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $$\frac{a^x-1}{x} \sim \log a $$ as $x\to 0$,

$$M^x - m^x = m^x \bigg( \left(\frac Mm\right)^x -1 \bigg) \sim m^x x\log\frac Mm \sim x\log \frac Mm$$

and so $$\frac{M^{x+1} -m^{x+1}}{M^x-m^x} \sim\frac{M-m}{x\log\frac Mm} := \frac Cx$$

$1/x$ pulled out of the $\Im$, $\Re$ makes these terms dominate and so

$$f(x) \sim \frac{1/x \times\Im (C)}{1/x \times\Re (C)} = \frac{\Im (C)}{\Re (C)}$$

is the limit.

Comment: I briefly accepted this as an answer because it seemed to work, but I discovered it fails in some cases though I'm not sure why. I'm trying to identify a pattern so I can work to resolve the problem.

Comment: There's clearly a straight/diagonal line based on the value of $b$ above which the expression for the limit breaks, but there's another possibly-curved boundary above that where it starts working again.

Comment: When $b$ is a positive real number, it doesn't seem to matter what value $a$ has, the expression always works. But when $b$ is negative-real-valued or complex-valued, there are portions of the complex plane where, when $a$ is located in those portions, the value of the expression $\frac{\Im(C)}{\Re(C)}$ is no longer the limit.

Comment: @Lawton What’s an example $(a,b)$ that doesn’t work?

Comment: Set $b = -1 + 0 i$ and let $a$ be any complex number with a negative real component and nonzero imaginary component. Under those conditions, the value for the limit given by the expression in your answer is no longer the value that the function $f(x)$ approaches from either direction.

Comment: @Lawton This may be due to an inconsistent use of $\sqrt{}$, $\log$. Since the limit involves doing these operations on complex numbers, you need to decide on a branch of $\arg z$ which gives particular branches of $\log$,$ \sqrt{}$. For example, you could take the cut plane $\mathbb C \setminus (-\inf,0]$.

Comment: I think I see. The graphing software I'm using, GeoGebra, must be choosing the wrong branch for the combinations of $a$ and $b$ that aren't working. Is there a convenient way to know which branch will work, and to represent that in the notation?

Comment: Using the expression $f(0) = \frac{\Im\left(\frac{M - m}{\ln\left(\left|\frac{M}{m}\right|\right) + ί \left(\arg\left(\frac{M}{m}\right) + 2 π n\right)}\right)}{\Re\left(\frac{M - m}{\ln\left(\left|\frac{M}{m}\right|\right) + ί \left(\arg\left(\frac{M}{m}\right) + 2 π n\right)}\right)}$, I can see that the variable $n$ should take one of the values $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ depending on the values of $a$ and $b$. I think I just need to figure out a function $g(a, b)$ that outputs whichever one of those three values is appropriate for a given combination.

Comment: Even to define $f(x)$, an implicit assumption is made for the branch. Now that can be really anything you like, as long as $a^2+4b$ and $\frac Mm$ do not lie on the branch cut.

Comment: Is there an equation that says where the branch cut is? It moves around as the argument of $b$ varies, and I haven't been able to figure out an exact formula for it yet.

Comment: I figured it out.